# awk output to variable

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

```
[Dd])   
echo"What is the record ID?" 
read rID
numA= awk -f "%" '{print $1'}< practice.txt
```

I cannot figure out how to set `numA =` to the output of the awk in order to compare `rID` and `numA`. `numA` is equal to the first field of a txt file which is separated by `%`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct syntax.

```
numA=$(awk -F'%' '{print $1}' practice.txt)
```

however, it will be easier to do comparisons in `awk` by passing the bash variable in.

```
awk -F'%' -v r="$rID" '$1==r{... do something ...}' practice.txt
```

since you didn't specify any details it's difficult to suggest more...

to remove rID matching line from the file do this

```
awk -F'%' -v r="$rID" '$1!=r' practice.txt > output
```

will print the lines where the condition is met ($1 not equal to rID), equivalent to deleting the ones which are equal.  You can mimic in place replacement by

```
awk ... practice.txt > temp && mv temp practice.txt
```

where you fill in ... from the line above.

Comment: it is basically a bash script that edits a .txt file.

Comment: devil is in the details.  You'll get more help and better suggestions if you can specify a simple output and expected output.

Comment: it has several fields per line, and this specific function removes the line specified by the user from the practice.txt file

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the output of any command in a variable via [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html):

```
numA=$(awk -F '%' '{print $1}' < practice.txt)
```

Unless your file contains only one line, however, the `awk` command you presented (as corrected above) is unlikely to be what you want to use.  If the `practice.txt` file contains, say, answers to multiple questions, one per line, then you probably want to structure the script altogether differently.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `awk`, just use parameter expansion:

```
numA=${rID%%\%*}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`` $ numA=`awk -F'%' '{ if($1 != $0) { print $1; exit; }}' practice.txt` ``

From the question, "numA is equal to the first field of a txt file which is separated by %"

- -F'%', meaning % is the only separator we care about
- if($1 != $0), meaning ignore lines that don't have the separator
- print $1; exit;, meaning exit after printing the first field that we encounter separated by %. Remove the exit if you don't want to stop after the first field.